# Javascript Date and JSON DateTime

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, date

I have a problem with Jquery function getJSON, the action url does not trigger because one of the parameter i am passing is a javascript date but the action expects c# DateTime..

Is it possible to format the Javascript Date to make it compatible for c# DateTime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the Datejs library (http://www.datejs.com/).  From my limited experience with it it's fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function taken from the [Mozilla Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Example.3a.c2.a0ISO_8601_formatted_dates):

```
/* use a function for the exact format desired... */
function ISODateString(d){
 function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
 return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
      + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'
}
```

.NET will have no problem handling an ISO formatted date. You can use [`DateTime.Parse(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) to handle the ISO formatted string.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying for a solution to get a Javascript date from the JSON representation (/Date(1350035703817)/) you can use [this function](http://sudarshanbhalerao.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/convert-json-date-into-javascript-date/):

```
function parseJsonDate(jsonDate) {
    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    var parts = /\/Date\((-?\d+)([+-]\d{2})?(\d{2})?.*/.exec(jsonDate);

    if (parts[2] == undefined) 
      parts[2] = 0;

    if (parts[3] == undefined) 
      parts[3] = 0;

    return new Date(+parts[1] + offset + parts[2]*3600000 + parts[3]*60000);
};
```

Worked for me like charm.

Answer (score 1):

I used this function, shorter than the above one.

```js
function ParseJsonDate(dateString) {
    var milli = dateString.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1');
    var date = new Date(parseInt(milli));
    return date;
}
```

Also found a method to convert them back:

```js
function ToJsonDate(date) {
    return '\/Date(' + date.getTime() + ')\/';
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to care about timezone information that is sometimes appended to JSON dates.